# Is it mandatory to have broadcast receiver as a separate file?

Tags: android, android-intent

I have declared an activity and a broadcast receiver in my manifest file, however, I have the code for `onReceive()` in my activity as a separate public class. When I try to trigger a broadcast from the adb command line I get a `classnotfound` error.

My question is, is it mandatory to have the `broadcastreceiver` as a separate class in a separate file ?

```
     @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ActivityAsDialogActivity.this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        :
        :
      }
public class TestEmail extends BroadcastReceiver{
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if (intent.getAction().equals(MYINTENT)){
                    Log.d("Manju ==>","ActivityAsDialogActivity, Got the intent"+MYINTENT);
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Don't panik but your time is up!!!!.",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }//end of if statment
        }//end of onReceiver
    }//end of Broadcast
}//end of class ActivityAsDialogActivity
```

below is manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.mot.activityasdialog"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".ActivityAsDialogActivity"
             android:excludeFromRecents="true"
             android:theme="@style/EmptyActivity"
             android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|uiMode">
             <!-- android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Dialog"
             android:label="@string/app_name" -->

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver android:name="com.mot.activityasdialog.ActivityAsDialogActivity.TestEmail" android:enabled="true">
           <intent-filter>
               <action android:name="com.mot.MANJU"></action>
           </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: And if they did not help you comment on them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: Yes it needs to be a different Class. And in a separate file.

Long answer: Since your BroadcastReceiver must be a subclass of BroadcastReceiver and your Activity must be a subclass of Activity and Java does not allow multiple inheritance and Activity and BroadcastReceiver are not related in a suitable fashion. Yes, it has to be two classes.

It seems to have to be in its own file too. I tried it and the system cannot find the BroadcastReceiver if it is an inner class. public or not.